# Change numbers to symbols in corresponding autor in RevTex (Latex)

Tags: pdftex

I am submitting a manuscript to the APL journal.

The editorial team required to write an asterisk with mail for the corresponding author as footnote.

By default the revtex file the AIP format. That uses numbers instead of asterisk.
I don't know if AIP format is wrong because it uses numbers or the editorial team just changed its mind recently.

How can I change the numbers to asterisks and include two corresponding authors with asterisk and the second one with dagger?

Thank you for the support.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

`revtex` uses a separate definition for the footnotes in the frontmatter. This can be adapted:

```
\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{footmisc}

\begin{document}

{
\makeatletter
\def\frontmatter@thefootnote{%
 \altaffilletter@sw{\@fnsymbol}{\@fnsymbol}{\csname c@\@mpfn\endcsname}%
}%
\makeatother

\author{A. B. Name}
\email{a@email.com}
\affiliation{University}

\author{C. D. Test}
\email{b@email.com}
\affiliation{School}
\maketitle
}

normal text with footnote\footnote{text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a good solution, but it does not work with the class loading as follows:

`\documentclass[twocolumn,prl,floatfix,superscriptaddress]{revtex4-2}`

Is it possible to modify the footnotes for affiliations instead and redefine it before the next author. I am asking this just to put asterisks for shared authors and keep the default numbering style for the affiliations.

By the way which counter is used here exactly, so that I can print and check its value?

Answer (score 0):

Footnote symbols can be easily modified. They are called by the command `\thefootnote`. And there is another macro `\fnsymbol` that converts footnote numbers to symbols: 1 is asterisk, 2 dagger, 3  double dagger, etc

So you can do

`\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}`

and if you want to revert (for the body of the article)

`\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[width=16cm, bottom=18cm]{geometry}

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\begin{document}

\title{About footnotes}
\author{Author 1\footnote{institution 1}
\and Author 2\footnote{institution 2}}

\maketitle

\setcounter{footnote}{0} % not sure it is required
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}

The text with normal\footnote{ie numeric} footnotes\footnote{blah blah}.
\end{document}
```

[image]